# Xcode compilation unexpected results

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, cocoapods

## ✅ Xcode 10.2.1

I have a project, on which I worked in Xcode 10.2.1. Suddenly it started to get stuck building one of my many pods (one of 2, inconsistently). Says something like "`Building <AppName>: <PodName> | Building 749 of 803 tasks`". And while idle, it gets stuck "Indexing Text".
[image: Stuck indexing text indefinitely]

Update: This version is unable to Build or Index ANY project I try. True even for unchanged presets.

#### SOLVED: Restarting my machine was the solution

---

## ✅ Xcode 11.0 Beta 1

Just to test, I've opened this project in Xcode 11 Beta (1) and it worked just fine. I was able to Build and Run, Archive but not Distribute (AppStore Connect says tool is unsupported).

---

## ❌ Xcode 11.0 Beta 4

The latest available Beta, however, Builds and Runs this project with no problems, however, [fails to Archive it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146714/xcode-11-0-beta-4-builds-and-runs-but-cant-archive).

---

#### Additional information

1. I tried cleaning, restarting; updating CocoaPods; reinstalling and reinitializing all Pods, nothing helped.
2. The issue appeared, seemingly, out of nowhere, not in between installing or updating any of the Pods.
3. It worked perfectly in Xcode 11.0 Beta 1, just as one would expect any version of Xcode to work with an .xcworkspace. No warnings, no errors, nothing.

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as a picture, so it can be found by users when searching.

Comment: @rmaddy Please, remove the "duplicate" status from this issue, since it really is not.

Comment: It was a duplicate of your original question. But you completely changed it so now it's not a duplicate. Instead of rewriting your question with a completely different issue, you should have posted a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this whole thing by restarting my machine.