# Xcode 11.0 Beta 4 Builds and Runs, but can't Archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, beta

My Swift project builds and runs normally, but fails every attempt to Archive with errors, caused by the following warnings:

```
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftFoundation'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftMetal'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDarwin'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftUIKit'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreFoundation'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftObjectiveC'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftDispatch'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreImage'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftQuartzCore'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreGraphics'
Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCore'
```

1. [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-linker-link-static-libraries-with-errors-ios) seems to be closely related, yet none of the proposed solutions seem to be helpful.
2. Errors appear under [this Pod](https://github.com/adamwaite/Validator) in Issue Navigator.
3. I was able to Archive this project in Xcode 11.0 Beta (1).
4. [Xcode 10.2.1 gets stuck compiling and indexing this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125780/xcode-compilation-unexpected-results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been running into the same issue, and it looks to be caused by the known bitcode issue in the Xcode beta release notes:

> Targets that contain Swift code with the Enable Bitcode build setting set to Yes fail to link correctly when built with the
> Archive action. (52804818)
>
> Workaround: Add a custom build setting with
> the name LD_VERIFY_BITCODE, and set it to NO. Make a note to yourself
> to delete this custom build setting once this issue is resolved.

You will need to add a User-Defined Build Setting since it doesn't show up as a normal Build Setting.  Click the + In your Build Settings to add one:

[image: Where To Add User-Defined Setting]

After Adding A User-Defined Setting, scroll all the way to the bottom of your build settings to find the one you just added, then modify it like so.

[image: Final User-Defined Setting]

Comment: I am having the same issue mentioned above. Prior to adding LD_VERIFY_BITCODE to my pod targets, the archive build was failing at the beginning of the process. After adding the workaround to my targets, it is failing the archive at the end (when it is linking). I am able to run the app on my device with no problem. Jeff, would you be able to be more specific about how to implement this fix? Where exactly should I be putting the workaround? Thanks for the help!